# How to send my app for review to Facebook?

Tags: facebook, windows-store-apps, review

I have written a **desktop** application and on the main interface there is a button to launch a Facebook status update form (**it is a different program**). In order for the status update to work, I need the **publish_actions** permission and for that I need to submit my app for review.

When I try to do that, it asks me to add a platform but when it comes to windows, it only accepts Windows 8 apps.

What can I do? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I had the same problem and found the solution.

What you have to do is submit it as Website and state you are submitting a Desktop Application. I submitted as Website following a suggestion from the Facebook Team in a [Bug Report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/350765051748773).

However, at first they rejected my review submission with the standard message "Your Website does not support Facebook Login". I submitted again explaining I have a Desktop Application and I was choosing the Platform Website following their suggestion from that link, and then they read my step-to-step screenshot instructions, approved some of the items and gave me feedback on the others.

Good luck!